# Apache, SVN and mod_python

Tags: svn, apache, mod-python, httpd.conf

We are using Apache 2.2 to server SVN (1.6.2) repositories on Windows. We use SSPI for authentication, and that's working. We have a number of different repositories, and use SVNParentPath in the httpd.conf to serve them. Something like:

```
<Location />
    DAV svn

    SVNParentPath c:\repos
    [SSPI stuff]
</Location>
```

So from a client I can browse to http://svn/repo1 or http://svn/repo2 (whatever repos are in c:\repos) and then see what's in the repositories.

However I now want to use mod_python to run python scripts in another URL, say http://svn/mpinfo .

I've tried adding a new location at the end of httpd.conf as follows:

```
<Location /mpinfo>
    SetHandler mod_python
    PythonHandler mod_python.testhandler
</Location>
```

as suggested at http://www.modpython.org/live/current/doc-html/inst-trouble.html . However when I browse to http://svn/mpinfo I get the following error:

```
<D:error>
<C:error/>
<m:human-readable errcode="720003">
Could not open the requested SVN filesystem
</m:human-readable>
</D:error>
```

If I change the location / url of the repositories to, for example, /svn, then I can browse to http://svn/mpinfo .

**Question:**

Is there anyway to have the repositories accessible from http://svn/reponame, but to have a special directory http://svn/mpinfo/ not parsed by svn, but instead parsed by mod_python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First up, do you have any joy if you change the order of the two Location directives? Ie., so that for '/mpinfo' comes before that of '/'.